# Custom truncation UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

I have a UITextView with strings that could be any length.

The size of the UITextView is fixed and if the string doesn't fit it needs to be truncated. I'm currently setting

```
self.titleTextView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

However this will break mid word.

What I'm after is for words to be preserved but an elipsis needs to be appended.

For example:

```
"This string needs truncating"
```

would end up being

```
"This string needs trun..."
```

if I use `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` when what I need is

```
"This string needs..."
```

What is the best way of achieving this style of truncation?